# Oracle SQL Insert statement for multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-insert

I have two tables `Alpha_Setting` and `Beta_View` as show below,

`Alpha_Setting`:

```
ID ( Sequence )
VIEW_ID
VIEW_TYPE
VIEW_VALUE
```

`Beta_View`

```
ID
VIEW_NAME
VIEW_TYPE
VIEW_CHECK
```

I would like to insert multiple ID from `Beta_View` into `VIEW_ID` in `Alpha_Setting`, how should I correct my SQL

```
insert into alpha_setting 
('',  
(select ID from beta_view where view_type = 'HERO' and (view_name = 'GREEN-All' or view_name = 'GREEN-New'),  
'super_power',   
'1000000');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
insert into alpha_setting (ID,VIEW_ID,VIEW_TYPE,VIEW_VALUE)
select '' /* or seq_name.nextval*/, ID,'super_power','1000000'
from beta_view 
where view_type = 'HERO' 
and view_name in('GREEN-All','GREEN-New','super_power','1000000');
```

or

```
insert into alpha_setting (ID,VIEW_ID,VIEW_TYPE,VIEW_VALUE)
select '' /* or seq_name.nextval*/, ID,'super_power','1000000'
from beta_view 
where view_type = 'HERO' 
and (view_name = 'GREEN-All' or view_name in('GREEN-New','super_power','1000000'));
```

I'm not sure which condition with `view_name` column is good for you.